# Battery charging time

Tags: battery-charging

I have a 4V 1.5A battery using it for led lights. What time it will take to charge full? Or on what factor this charging time depends? And how to calculate this

Comment: The permissible charging rate for a battery depends on the battery chemistry and construction.  Some battery types can tolerate much faster charging than others.

Comment: You said '1.5 A'. Do you mean 1.5 Ah? It should be on the battery label. If so then edit your question. Units matter.

Comment: No.. Its 4V 1.5A only

Comment: Do you know what kind of battery it is, or where it came from? Is it NiMh, NiCd, lithium? Your question will end up getting closed if you don't provide more information. It is rare to find a rechargeable battery which does not include a capacity in units of Ah or mAh. Please check carefully.

Comment: What does the supplier recommend?

Comment: When you reply to a comment you should start it with "@XXX", with XXX being the name/avatar of the poster you're replying to.  That way a notification will be sent to their inbox and they won't have to make unnecessary trips to your question looking for replies. As far as your question goes, it makes no sense, since without knowing the capacity of the battery, its recommended charging current, its chemistry, and its state of discharge, any answer would just be a guess.  Can you post a data sheet or a link to one, please?

Answer (score 1):

Batteries are usually rated in Ampere hours (Ah), which is Amps x hours. So 1Ah could be 1Amp for 1 hour, or 2A for 0.5 hours, or 0.5A for 2 hours etc.

If you have a 1.5Ah battery and charge it at 1A then it should take 1.5 hours to fully charge from empty. However, depending on the battery's chemistry it may have to be charged at a lower rate, and current may have to be reduced once the voltage rises to its maximum permitted value.

Before deciding how to charge your battery you need to know what type of chemistry it uses. This may not be written on it, but you can get a clue from the rated voltage and physical shape. 4V suggests a 2 cell Lead Acid battery, because Lead-acid chemistry develops 2V per cell. However this an unusual configuration (6V and 12V are much more common), so it might be something else such as a single Li-ion cell (which is 4.1~4.2V fully charged).

If you charge a battery incorrectly it may catch fire or explode, so it is vitally important to know what its charging requirements are. If you aren't sure then don't do it!